# basic routing in Codeigniter/Pyrocms

Tags: codeigniter, routes, pyrocms

I have a module in pyrocms its called event, since I can't call it event due to the already existing events class

I'd like to have the localhost/events url to lead to the event module though, so I've tried setting a route in event/config/routes.php

with this line

```
$route['events/(:any)?']        = 'event/$1';
```

but that doesn't work - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What errors does it throw? Do you have an Event controller?

Comment: Never say "doesn't work" without a description of what went wrong. Are you getting a 404, fatal error, blue screen of death? Who knows if you just say "doesn't work". It's useless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question mark may interfer with the routing, so it should be:

```
$route['events/(:any)'] = 'event/$1';
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to point to class/method ie:

```
$route['events/(:any)'] = 'class/method/$1';
```

`(:any)` and `(:num)` are wildcards.  You can use your own patterns.

Take this example(for demonstration purposes):

```
// www.mysite.com/search/price/1.00-10.00
$route['search/price/(:any)'] = 'search/price/$1';
```

`$1` is equal to the wildcard `(:any)`

so you could say

```
public function price($range){
     if(preg_match('/(\d.+)-(\d.+)/', $range, $matches)){
         //$matches[0] = '1.00-10.00'
         //$matches[1] = '1.00'
         //$matches[2] = '10.00'
     }

     //this step is not needed however, we can simply pass our pattern into the route.
     //by grouping () our pattern into $1 and $2 we have a much cleaner controller

     //Pattern: (\d.+)-(\d.+) says group anything that is a digit and fullstop before/after the hypen( - ) in the segment 
}
```

So now the route becomes

```
$route['search/price/(\d.+)-(\d.+)'] = 'search/price/$1/$2';
```

Controller

```
public function price($start_range, $end_range){}
```